# Typescript: No encuentra la clase y Dice que una variable ya esta declarada

Tags: html, typescript

estoy trabajando en una aplicación pequeña pero en en el archivo index.ts me dice que la clase Expenses no existe y la variable que definí me dice que ya existe y me marca como erro de TS2304 adjunto el código es un proyecto de typescript simple aun no estoy trabajando con angular el error es de typescript pero en el terminal me aparece el error mientras que en el código no me aparece ningun error estare agradecido si me ayudan con esto pls

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>Vida MRR</header>
    <main>
        <section id="display"></section>
        <section id="editor">
            <div id="input-container">
                <input type="text" id="title">
                <input type="number" id="cost">
                <select name="" id="currency">
                    <option value="MXN">MXM</option>
                    <option value="USD">USD</option>
                </select>
                <button id="bAdd">Agregar</button>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="items"></section>
    </main>
    <script src="js/expenses.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.ts

```
const bAdd = document.querySelector('#bAdd') as HTMLButtonElement;
const inputTitle = document.querySelector('#title') as HTMLInputElement;
const inputCost = <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('#cost');
const inputCurrency:HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('#currency');

const expenses = new Expenses('USD');

bAdd!.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(inputTitle!.value != '' && inputCost!.value != '' && !isNaN(parseFloat(inputCost.value))){
        const title = inputTitle!.value;
        const cost:number = parseFloat(inputCost!.value);
        const currency:Currency = <Currency>(inputCurrency!.value);

        expenses.add({title: title, cost:{number: cost, currency:currency}});

        render();
    }else{
        alert('Llena los campos vacios');
    }
});

function render() {
    let html = '';

    expenses.getItems().forEach(item => {
        const {id, title, cost} = item;
        const {number, currency} = cost;
        html += `
        <div class="item">
            <div><span class="currency">${currency}</span>${number}</div>"
            <div>${title}</div>
            <div><button class="bEliminar" data-id="${id}">Eliminar</button></div>
        </div>`;
    });

    $('#items').innerHTML = html;
    $('display').textContent = expenses.getTotal();

    $$('.bEliminar').forEach(bEliminar =>{
        bEliminar.addEventListener("click", e =>{
            const id = (e.target as HTMLButtonElement).getAttribute("data-id");

            expenses.remove(parseInt(id!));

            render();
        });
    });
}

function $(selector: string):HTMLElement{
    return document.querySelector(selector) as HTMLElement;
}

function $$(selector: string):NodeListOf<HTMLElement>{
    return document.querySelectorAll(selector) as NodeListOf<HTMLElement>;
}
```

expenses.ts

```
type Currency = 'MXN' | 'USD'

interface Price{
    number: number,
    currency: Currency
}

interface ExpensesItem{
    id?:number,
    title:string,
    cost:Price
}

interface IExpenses{
    expenses: ArrayList<ExpensesItem>
    finalCurrency: Currency, 
    add(item:ExpensesItem):boolean
    get(index:number):ExpensesItem|null,
    getTotal():string,
    remove(id:number):boolean
}

class ArrayList<T>{
    private items:T[];
    
    constructor(){
        this.items = [];
    }

    add(item:T):void{
        this.items.push(item);
    }

    get(index:number):T|null{
        const item = this.items.filter((x:T,i:number)=>{
            return i == index;
        });

        if(item.length==0){
            return null;
        }else{
            return item[0];
        }
    }
    createFrom(value:T[]):void{
        this.items = [...value];
    }

    getAll():T[]{
        return this.items;
    }
}

class Expenses implements IExpenses{
    expenses: ArrayList<ExpensesItem>;
    finalCurrency: Currency;

    constructor(currency:Currency){
        this.finalCurrency = currency;
        this.expenses = new ArrayList<ExpensesItem>();
    }

    private count = 0;

    add(item: ExpensesItem): boolean {
        item.id = this.count;
        this.count++;
        this.expenses.add(item);
        return true;
    }
    get(index:number): ExpensesItem | null {
        return this.expenses.get(index);
    }

    getItems():ExpensesItem[]{
        return this.expenses.getAll();
    }

    getTotal(): string {
        const total = this.getItems().reduce((acc, item) =>{
            return acc += this.convertcurrency(item, this.finalCurrency);
        }, 0);
        return `${this.finalCurrency} ${total.toFixed(2).toString()}`
    }
   
    remove(id: number): boolean {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }

    private convertcurrency(item: ExpensesItem, currency: Currency):number{
        switch(item.cost.currency){
            case 'USD':
                switch (currency) {
                    case 'MXN':
                        return item.cost.number * 20;
                    default:
                        return item.cost.number;
                }
                break;
                case 'MXN':
                    switch (currency) {
                        case 'USD':
                            return item.cost.number / 20.22;
                        default:
                            return item.cost.number;
                    }
                break;
                default:
                    return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

imagen del mensaje del error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Copia el contenido del archivo *expenses.ts* al inicio del archivo *index.ts*, borra la palabra clave `export` y elimina el archivo *index.ts* ya que `export` o `import` convierte esa clase en módulo y tendrías que utilizar **webpack** para manejar módulos.

Comment: ya lo hice y ahora si me marca el error en las partes que me decia la terminal

Comment: qué error te marca ahora en el terminal?

Comment: el mismo que esta en la imagen pero ahora si me marca el error en el codigo

Comment: puedes enviarme todos los archivos de tu proyecto para poder replicar el error?

Comment: tienes un correo para poder enviartelos?

Comment: mejor te mando un enlace para que lo puedas descargar https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1i9kfdO7fFbQVcQmOMco3vwy84AhqZJn6?usp=sharing

Comment: qué comando y en que ruta ejecutas para generar los .js desde los .ts?

Comment: estos son los que uso: tsc index.ts
tsc expenses.ts

Comment: Proyect/src/archivo.ts

Comment: actualice la respuesta, creo q podría servirte

Comment: lo hice como lo indicaste, pero ahora me marca el erro en esta linea "const expenses = new Ex.Expenses('USD');"

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130947/discussion-between-galaxy-and-germn-marcelo-celestino-chvez).